# How to create a SQL query with optional parameters in Python Flask?

Tags: python, sql-server, forms, flask

How to create a SQL query with optional parameters in Python Flask?

I use a HTML form to filter the data from a SQL table. The form has multiple optional fields. How can I create a SQL query based on the filled fields in the form?

For example, if the users fill in 3 fields "name", "amount" and "itemtype", the query is like:

```
rows = cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM items WHERE name = ? AND amount=? AND itemtype = ? """, name, amount, itemtype).fetchall()
```

If they skip "amount", the query is like:

```
rows = cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM items WHERE name = ? AND itemtype = ? """, name, itemtype).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 4):

<s>I prefer to use Python's `format` string function for this. It's splitting hairs, but `format` allows to set name in the string, so it's *technically* more explicit. However, I would suggest using `**kwargs` instead of `*args`, so you don't have to rely on magic.</s>

**UPADATE 2019**

This was a **terrible** answer. You never, ever, EVER want to take user generated data and interpolate it directly into a SQL query. It is **imperative** that you always sanitize user input in order to protect against [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Python has defined a [database API specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) that any database package that **is not** an ORM like [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) should implement. Long story short, you should be **NEVER, EVER, EVER** use `str.format()`, `%`, or "fstrings" to interpolate data into your SQL queries.

The database API specification provides a way to safely interpolate data into queries. Every python database interface should have a `Cursor` class that is returned from a `Connection` object. The `Cursor` class will implement a method named [`execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15). This obviously will execute a query, **but** it will also have a second argument–usually called `args`. According to the specification:

> Parameters may be provided as sequence or mapping and will be bound to variables in the operation. Variables are specified in a database-specific notation (see the module's paramstyle attribute for details).

By "sequence", it means that `args` can be a `list` or `tuple`, and by "mapping", it means that `args` can also be a `dict`. Depending on the package, the way to specify where your data should be interpolated may differ. There are six options for this. Which formatting the package you're using can be found in the [`paramstyle`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) constant of the package. For instance, [`PyMySQL`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute)(and most implementations of the spec that I've used) uses `format` and `pyformat`. A simple example would be:

**format**

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM t WHERE a = %s, b = %s;', (1, 'baz'))
```

**pyformat**

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM t WHERE a = %(foo)s, b = %(bar)s;', {'foo': 1, 'bar': 'baz'})
```

Both of these would execute as:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE a = 1, b = 'baz';
```

You should make sure to explore the documentation of the database API package you're using. One extremely helpful thing I came across using [`psycopg2`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/index.html), a PostgresSQL package, was its `extras` module. For instance, a common problem when trying to insert data securely is encountered when inserting multiple rows at once. `psycopg2` has a clever solution to this problem in its [`execute_values`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) function. Using `execute_values`, this code:

```
execute_values(cursor, "INSERT INTO t (a, b) VALUES %s;", ((1, 'foo'), (2, 'baz')))
```

... is executed as:

```
"INSERT INTO t (a, b) VALUES (1, 'foo'), (2, 'baz');"
```

Comment: This is a better solution. You missed a quote somewhere though! :D

Comment: You didn't answer the question of how to deal with optional parameters. The question already used cursor.execute with args.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the current answer actually addresses "what if I have parameters that are optional?", so I have a similar scenario that I'm solving like this -

```
    def some_func(a, b = None, c = None):

        where_clause = f"id = {str(a)}"

        if b:
            where_clause += f" and lower(b) = lower('{b}')"

        if c:
            where_clause += f" and c = {str(c)}"

        query = f"select * from table where {where_clause}"
```

Not the most scalable solution but it works if you only have a few optional parameters. You could refactor the clause-builder into its own function to build the string and accept parameters for any transforms that need to be applied (lower, etc).

I also assume there are some ORM's with functionality that solves this but while working on a small app this is sufficient for me.